# Can't get this div centered?

Tags: css, wordpress

Halfway down this page is the "our team" section using the Wordpress plugin Huge-IT Portfolio: http://dev.doubleaevents.com/ . When I resize my browser to smaller sizes, each image rearranges but the div is not centered. I've tried auto left and right margins, and setting max widths, which seems to work when I inspect the element... but when I make the same changes in my style sheet I can't seem to get the whole div centered!

Ideas?

Comment: For me everything works fine. Could you show use a screenshot?

Comment: in media query lower than 769px put this css: .portelement{left:50% !important; transform:translate(-50%) !important;}

Comment: @destinatioN http://oi65.tinypic.com/20zd6ki.jpg

is there a way to embed that image on stackoverflow? Sorry, I'm new!

Comment: Araz thanks for the quick response! I tried your solution and couldn't get it to work. Is this correct?

@media screen and (max-width: 769px){
  .portelement{left:50% !important; transform:translate(-50%) !important;}
}

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Try adding this:

```
@media(max-width: 769px){#huge_it_portfolio_container_1{
margin: 0 30% !important;

}}
```

Clear your browser cache and reload maybe it'll solve the problem.

[image: Working perfectly with the CSS rule above]

Comment: Cleared my cache, still not working :( I'm in chrome and it's when my browser is sized under 1000px wide if that makes a difference on your end?

Comment: It was an error on my part. I made some changes and those images are now centered as wanted it to be. Add the css again.

Comment: Thanks @Abk, I'm still not seeing a difference when I add the css to my style sheet though.

I did get a little closer by adding:
section#huge_it_portfolio_content_1 {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  width: 85% !important;
}

but it's still a bit off.

Comment: Check out the image in the answer. Is that not what you want to achieve?

Comment: no, I still want the columns of images, just having all the content centered - as opposed to everything in one column.